# Why is typeof null === "object", when null is considered a primitive, and primitives cannot be objects?

Tags: javascript, object, types, primitive

I know that typeof (null) === "object", but I don't understand why this is acceptable in javascript. According to [JavaScript data types and data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) over at MDN, `null` is a primitive and yet according to their own [Glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive);

> A primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not
>   an object and has no methods. In JavaScript, there are 6 primitive
>   data types: string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol (new in
>   ECMAScript 2015).

a primitive must not be an object. I don't understand why this hasn't been fixed in later releases of javascript.

Comment: It's not "fixed" because billions of lines of JavaScript out there depend on the existing behavior. Such "Why is X like Y?" about programming languages are always difficult to really answer, but in this case I suspect the original thinking was that `null` is a value that is used to mean that no object is being referenced.

Comment: @Barmar If it's an exact duplicate, why don't you link to the duplicate.

Comment: It **is** linked to the duplicate.

Comment: Not for me... because I'd like to see this duplicate question to get my answer.

Comment: @KyleRichardson You don't see the link above the question, or in the **Linked** section of the sidebar?

Comment: My apologizes, it was at the top of the screen and i had to scroll up. It was not shown with the closing statement that I was linked to from comment alert. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @KyleRichardson: yeah, that is a UX fail when related messages are visually separated; forcing to user to have to remember a certain pattern. Don't make me think!

Comment: I've never had a question I asked before marked as duplicate. I was unaware that it was even there. Definitely a UX failure.